# Highchart / Highstock theme for all charts (here french format)

Tags: macros, formatting, highcharts, french

I spend a lot of time to format each highcharts elements to french format (texts, dates, buttons, etc..)

I propose a little "macro" french theme for your applications using highcharts.

```
Highcharts.theme = {

lang: {

    /*------ Dates translation ------ */
    months: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
        'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
    weekdays: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi',
        'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
    shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil',
        'Aout', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Déc'],

    /*------ Texts translation ------ */
    downloadPNG: 'Télécharger en image PNG',
    downloadJPEG: 'Télécharger en image JPEG',
    downloadPDF: 'Télécharger en document PDF',
    downloadSVG: 'Télécharger en document Vectoriel',
    exportButtonTitle: 'Export du graphique',
    loading: 'Chargement en cours...',
    printButtonTitle: 'Imprimer le graphique',
    resetZoom: 'Réinitialiser le zoom',
    resetZoomTitle: 'Réinitialiser le zoom au niveau 1:1',
    printChart: 'Imprimer le graphique',

    /*------ Number Formate ------ */
    thousandsSep: ' ', // ex: 52 000
    decimalPoint: ',' // ex: 1 525,50
},
credits: {
    /*------ Unrelated but usefull to remove credits in each charts ------ */
    enabled: false
},
rangeSelector: {
    /*------ Highstock date range selector (the 2 little inputs in right corner) ------ */
    inputDateFormat: '%e %b %Y', // ex: 8 Avr 2014
    inputEditDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y', // After clicking on item ex : 13/06/2014
    // Processing After enter key pressed : apply the 13/06/2014 format
    inputDateParser: function (value) {
        value = value.split('/');
        return Date.UTC(
                parseInt(value[2]),
                parseInt(value[1]) - 1,
                parseInt(value[0])
                );
    },
    /*------ Highstock zoom selector (on the left top side) ------ */
    buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1 M' // useless translate :p
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 6,
            text: '6 M' // useless translate :p
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1 A' // translate Y in A (Année in french)
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            count: 1,
            text: 'Tout' // translate all in Tout
        }],
    selected: 2, // Here we force to select 6 M
    inputEnabled: true // Active Inputs
},
};

Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

You have to add this file(charts-theme.js) between the highstock.js and your .highcharts function.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://saur/assets/backend/pages/scripts/charts-theme.js"></script>
<script src="http://saur/assets/backend/pages/scripts/charts.js"></script>
```

Obviously, you can use it with different language, or just to define some "general" uses.

Hope it help.

Comment: It works very well. Thank you very much for sharing!

Comment: This is a great idea.. have you considered putting it in github?

Comment: Not really, you think it can be helpful ?